# Angular - Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: angular

I have a method that controls an input from showing/hiding on my page which uses the `*ngIf` directive. There is a button that toggles the showing/hiding which is essentially adding/removing it from the page.

I am getting an error `Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges` when I toggle this. `Show -> Hide (Fine) -> Show -> Hide (Error)`.

Here is the method being called. My button to toggle this input calls **cancelEditMode()**.

```
closeEditMode() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this._mapsService.rulesInEditMode.length; i++) {
        if (this._mapsService.rulesInEditMode[i].parentID == this.parentRule.controls['RuleParentID'].value && this._mapsService.rulesInEditMode[i].attributeID == this.ruleAttributeData.AttributeID) {
            this._mapsService.rulesInEditMode.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

}

cancelEditMode() {

    this.
    ruleAttributeForm.
    valueChanges.
    subscribe(form => {
        this.closeEditMode();
    });

    // Reset to initial input before the user made 2-way binding changes
    this.ruleAttributeForm.controls['AttributeValue'].setValue(this.initialValueInput, { emitEvent: true })

}
```

This appears to be an issue with the form subscription and setting of the value. If the only thing I call in `cancelEditMode()` is `closeEditMode()`, I do not get the error no matter how many times I toggle.

My goal for this method is that it sets the value of the form control and once it has been set, we then close the input (toggle `*ngIf` to `false`). Somewhere along the line, it doesn't like this.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you provided plunker example we would have more ideas about what's going on.

Comment: Either a reproduction code or a full view of your relevant code. Hard to see what's going on just by looking at one piece of the puzzle. Please provide either one of those.